# SQL Using multiple joins to fill in null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have two tables - one with jobs data and one with address data.

The address_data (D) is as follows:

|  LotNumber  |  PlanNumber  |  StreetNumber  |  (Other Info not relevant)  |

The jobs_data (J):  *For many of these entries, only lot + plan number is given

| LotNumber | PlanNumber | StreetNumber | (Other Info) |

I want to fill in J.StreetNumber with D.StreetNumber field when it is Null by joining
J.LotNumber = D.LotNumber And J.PlanNumber = D.PlanNumber

My first attempt:

```
INSERT INTO Jobs_Data (StreetNumber)
SELECT D.StreetNumber
FROM Address_Data D
JOIN Jobs_Data J ON J.LotNumber::varchar = D.LotNumber::varchar
JOIN Address_Data DA ON J.PlanNumber::varchar = DA.PlanNumber::varchar
WHERE J.StreetNumber IS NULL ;
```

Within the Jobs_Data (J) table, my first attempt added a blank extra row for every row of Address Data (D) and filled in only the street number columns. Further up the table, my jobs data remained unchanged with the same missing street numbers.

Also I get the feeling that NULL may not be the same as my empty StreetNumber columns which are just blank (with no spaces)?

I'm hoping some SQL gurus may be able to solve this for me!

Comment: format your code properly?

Comment: what are the datatypes of LotNumber and PlanNumber in both tables?

Comment: These are all character varying (varchar) except J.LotNumber (I just realised), would this have effected the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, much appreciated. I have found the solution to this, which was simpler than I expected and did not require an 'INSERT INTO' or 'JOIN' statement:

```
UPDATE Jobs_Data
SET StreetNumber = D.StreetNumber
FROM Address_Data D
WHERE Jobs_Data.PlanNumber = D.PlanNumber
AND Jobs_Data.LotNumber = D.LotNumber
AND Jobs_Data.StreetNumber IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also I get the feeling that NULL may not be the same as my empty StreetNumber columns which are just blank (with no spaces)?

If the joins work (after simplification) with whatever are the datatypes, then to fix the above you will have to fix only the where clause as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Jobs_Data (StreetNumber)
SELECT D.StreetNumber
FROM Address_Data D
JOIN Jobs_Data J ON J.LotNumber=D.LotNumber and J.PlanNumber=D.PlanNumber
WHERE trim(J.StreetNumber) IS NULL and trim(D.StreetNumber) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, this stopped the query from adding a row for all address data (D) entries to the jobs data (J). However, this added 400 or so blank entries after the jobs data with only a StreetNumber, whilst the Jobs street numbers are still missing. Could an UPDATE be the solution instead of INSERT INTO? Appreciate your help